# Segmentation fault when trying to push_back to a std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a `Token` class which is structured as follows:

```
class Token {
    public:
        void* value;
        token_type type; // enum to know which type of data is it storing inside value
        unsigned int line;

        Token() = default;

        Token(void* new_value, token_type new_type):
            value(new_value), type(new_type)
            {}

        ~Token() {
            //free the memory occupied by the object pointed to by value based on it's type
            //this also handles the case of the Token being an instantiation of Statement
        }
};
```

Then there's the class Statement:

```
class Statement: public Token {
    public:
        std::vector<Token*>* list;
        unsigned int lenght = 0;

        Statement() {
            list = new std::vector<Token*>;
            Token((void*) list, statement);
        }
};
```

Basically, when creating a Statement, the inner Token knows it's holding a statement because there is a specific `token_type` type for that. The inner Token does the cleanup of the vector in its destructor so it has to have a pointer to that vector in its `value` attribute, but we also have a copy of that pointer in the Statement so we don't need to do the cast from `void*` to `std::vector<Token>*` each time;

Now, what I am trying to do is this:

```
std::string* value = new std::string("Sample text");
Token* to_be_pushed = new Token((void*) value, string); //the object pointed to by value will be deleted in this Token's destructor

Statement* new_statement = new Statement;

new_statement->list->push_back(to_be_pushed);

delete new_statement; //Token destructor gets called; It knows it's a statement,
//so it knows value is pointing to a std::vector<Token*> object, and it deletes each pointer in that vector and then the vector itself
```

The problem, however, is I am getting a Segmentation fault error on the line where I push `to_be_pushed` at the end of `new_statement->list`.

I've tried breaking that line in two pieces, and I know the problem is when I am calling `list->push_back`, not when accessing `new_statement->list`.

Here's the backtrace I got from gdb:

```
#0  0xb6e51410 in memmove ()
from /system/lib/libc.so
#1  0x2a0066f8 in std::__copy_move<true, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<Token*>
(__first=0x2a0198d0, __last=0x0,
__result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:378
#2  0x2a006640 in std::__copy_move_a<true, Token**, Token**> (__first=0x2a0198d0, __last=0x0,
__result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:395
#3  0x2a007070 in std::__copy_move_a2<true, Token**, Token**> (__first=0x2a0198d0, __last=0x0,
__result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:432
#4  0x2a007010 in std::copy<std::move_iterator<Token**>, Token**> (__first=..., __last=...,
__result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:464
#5  0x2a006fb0 in std::__uninitialized_copy<true>::__uninit_copy<std::move_iterator<Token**>, Token**> (__first=..., __last=...,
__result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:93
#6  0x2a006f70 in std::uninitialized_copy<std::move_iterator<Token**>, Token**> (__first=...,
__last=..., __result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:123
#7  0x2a006eec in std::__uninitialized_copy_a<std::move_iterator<Token**>, Token**, Token*> (
__first=..., __last=...,
__result=0x2a019908)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:279
#8  0x2a006dc0 in std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<Token**, Token**, std::allocator<Token*> > (__first=0x2a0198d0, __last=0x0,
__result=0x2a019908, __alloc=...)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:300
#9  0x2a007264 in std::vector<Token*, std::allocator<Token*> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<Token* const&> (this=0x2a019908,
__args=@0x2a0198e8: 0x2a0198d0)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/vector.tcc:457
#10 0x2a005b70 in std::vector<Token*, std::allocator<Token*> >::push_back (this=0x2a019908,
__x=@0x2a0198e8: 0x2a0198d0)
at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/bits/stl_vector.h:1049
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? Is it the code I've posted fault?

Comment: `Token((void*) list, statement);` You seem to think that calls the base class constructor. It does not: the base class is initialized with the default constructor. Instead, it creates a temporary unnamed instance of `Token`, which is immediately destroyed. In other words, it's a no-op. This is further exacerbated by the fact that `Token()` default constructor leaves its members uninitialized, containing random garbage.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik how could I achieve the right behaviour, i.e. storing in the Token's `value` and in the Statement's `list` the same pointer to a new `std::vector<Token*>` object? The pointer is however already being stored the right way in `list`, so my bug is independent on that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You haven't shown `~Token()` destructor, but presumably it tries to access its member variables, which are, again, uninitialized and containing random garbage; whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior. I'm pretty sure the problem I've pointed out is in fact directly relevant to the behavior you observe.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik ok then, fixing that and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Token((void*) list, statement);
```

You are expecting this to call the superclass's constructor. This does not call the constructor. All this does is construct a temporary object, which then gets immediately destroyed. The only way to call the superclass's constructor is in the initialization section of the subclass:

```
 Statement() : Token(...)
```

However in your case, you need to initialize the subclass, namely its `list` member, before invoking the constructor for the superclass. This cannot be easily done. Although there are ways around this, this is really a symptom of a fundamental design flaw with this class hierarchy.

You have two options:

1. Reimplement your class hierarchy. The way your classes are designed are fundamentally wrong. Properly-designed C++ code should never need to do tricks like casting to `void *`.
2. Initialize `Token` manually, in the body of the `Statement`'s constructor. Use `Token`'s default constructor, then fix it up in the `Statement`'s constructor body.

However, even if you try the #2 approach, you will likely find other problems later down the road, specifically: your `Statement` class [violates the Rule Of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). That's almost a guaranteed certainty to cause a number of difficult to track down bugs.

The right answer here will be to step back, and redesign your class hierarchy completely. And getting rid of `new` allocation in favor of proper usage of C++ library containers would also be a plus.

There are many ways to redesign this class hierarchy, and without additional information it is not possible to suggest the right class design.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks for your answer. I am just a beginner with proper OOP (i come from Lua) so dirty code is normal I hope. Can you show me some links on how to get rid of `void*` please? They keep telling me it's wrong but I can't find online a better way to do what `void*` does for me perfectly: storing a pointer to an object of unknown type.

Comment: "The inner Token does the cleanup of the vector in its destructor" This would be just one of the problems. `Statement` constructed it, so `Statement` should destroy it. That's proper class design. Furthermore, there's nothing "unknown" about it. Its type is always the same.

Comment: If I think about it, Statement doesn't need to be a subclass of Token. However yes, the type of `value` is unknown in advance because it could be storing a `std::string` and thus having a `type` attribute containing `token_type::string`, or it could contain a double whith `token_type::number` and so on.

Comment: ... and the right solution would be to define a base class, and derive each possible value of the metadata used by `token`, and store a `std::shared_ptr` to the base class. Again, there's no need for a `void *` here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last bit some more please? Again, just a link would be helpful.

Comment: This cannot exactly be explained in a few paragraphs, [find a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Did you mean having a single class for each of the subtypes of Token (like, one for `token_type::string` storing a `std::string` and bla bla bla)? I don't see how this solves the problem, as I will anyway need to store them as a Token* somewhere.